# Primary entity vs secondary entities about Core Data saving objects

Tags: swift, core-data

I am working on a core data application and currently I have the methods setup correctly to save the primary object saves the name of the users deck but it doesn't save recall the secondary object even though the method used to save both is identical. The primary does save second though and I am wondering if it matters the order that objects are saved. I know it is a relational but I figured it wouldn't matter if the secondary was called to save prior to the primary. I am still new to core data so just a simple answer is enough. If I need to save the primary entity object first then I will build the app in such a way that such occurs, else I may have to relook at the code to figure out why it isn't recalling.

This is the code that is supposed to save prior to the name being saved in a relational manner:

```
@IBAction func buttonWarrior(sender: AnyObject) {

    let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName("ClassSelection", inManagedObjectContext: classMOC!)

    let newObject = ClassSelection(entity: entity!,insertIntoManagedObjectContext: classMOC)

    newObject.classname = "Warrior"

    var error: NSError?

    classMOC?.save(&error)

    if let err = error {

        println(err)

    } else {

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("popOver", sender: self)

    }
}
```

This is the code used to store the primary object which is a different viewcontroller.swift file than the other one. This is presented as a popover box over the secondary object. This part works fine and recalls correctly :

```
@IBAction func enterButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Deck",inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!)

    let storeDeck = Deck(entity: entityDescription!,insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)

    storeDeck.deckname = usersDeckName.text

    var error: NSError?

    managedObjectContext?.save(&error)

    if let err = error {

        status.text = err.localizedFailureReason


    } else {

        usersDeckName.text = ""
        status.text = "Deck Saved"
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showCardSelection", sender: self)

    }

}
```

The recall method I am trying to use may not make sense in it's current iteration as I have been trying many different methods :

```
@IBOutlet weak var decksListed: UITableView!

let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

var savedDecksClass = [ClassSelection]()

var frc: NSFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController()

var frcClasses: NSFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController()

func getFetchedResultsController() -> NSFetchedResultsController {
    frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: listFetchRequest(), managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

return frc

}

func getClassesFetchedResultsController() -> NSFetchedResultsController {

    frcClasses = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: classFetchRequest(), managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

return frcClasses

}

func listFetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest {

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Deck")
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "deckname", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

    return fetchRequest

}
func classFetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest {

    let fetchRequestClasses = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Deck")
    let classSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "classname", ascending: true)
    fetchRequestClasses.sortDescriptors = [classSortDescriptor]

    return fetchRequestClasses
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    let numberofRowsInSection = frc.sections?[section].numberOfObjects

    return numberofRowsInSection!

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("usersDeck", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    let listed = frc.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Deck
    cell.textLabel?.text = listed.deckname
    let listedClass = frcClasses.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! ClassSelection
    cell.detailTextLabel!.text = listedClass.classname
    return cell

}

func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {

    decksListed.reloadData()

}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    frcClasses = getClassesFetchedResultsController()
    frcClasses.delegate = self
    frc.performFetch(nil)
    frc = getFetchedResultsController()
    frc.delegate = self
    frc.performFetch(nil)

}
```

I hope this is enough to give you an idea. I checked the relationships out and they all seem to be correct in the model. I apologize in advanced for the way some of the code looks I plan on shrinking it down after all the editing is done and working.

Comment: The `save` method of `NSManagedObjectContext` saves ALL changes in the context.  So the sequence in which they are created is irrelevant. Edit your post to include the code - there is some other problem going on.

Comment: I modified the post like asked I hope this gives you an idea as to what I did, and what I am probably doing wrong. Also not sure if it matters for a simple core data model but I am just using the App Delegate as the persistent store coordinator as I haven't been brave enough to experiment outside of that yet and am self teaching myself. I didn't think it would matter much for a simple application that only stores basic stats.

Comment: Sorry I realized one thing I forgot to mention in the fetch request that is calling the Deck with the "classname" I tried using the actual class which is ClassSelection and not deck and still had the same error popup which was the Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0x0)

Comment: Thanks for posting the code.  It's difficult to see the precise source of the error, though I am concerned that you are using two FRCs for a single table view.  I think fixing it might take a few iterations - are you happy to use chat, to avoid clogging up the comments?

Comment: I am unsure if I have unlocked chat yet how many post +'s do you need for that?

Comment: I think you're OK - 20 is required - try it [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86547/room-for-pbasdf-and-matthew)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to pbasdf for helping me with this one. The chat he opened actually contained exactly what was needed to be done. I just wasn't saving the relationship and passing the object from one view controller to the next. After showing me exactly how to do so with an example I figured out the rest! Basically it would never have been able to recall the object as it never knew that they were related....foolish me! Thanks again!